# C program getting compiled but not showing output

Tags: c

I am not sure why my program is not showing "Hello World". I am trying by executing only `printf()`. Is there anything I am missing here?

Below is my complete program

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    printf("Hello World");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: online compiler? try adding a `\n` at the end of the printf statement.

Comment: or, `fflush(stdout)` after the current printf.

Comment: @SouravGhosh, i think before the program exits, the buffer will flush.

Comment: @Haris please note the first two words in my very first comment. :)

Comment: How do you run your program? What compiler are you using`Which version of the compiler? On which operating system?

Comment: I have just downloaded a compiler using this location : http://sourceforge.net/projects/turbocforwindows-9/

Comment: Turbo C? It's 80's. Forget of it's existence. It's likely it shows the input, but the console is closing right away.

Comment: So Which one I should use ? can you help

Comment: GCC or MSVC. Probably the latter will be better for you.

Comment: [Here's a list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_integrated_development_environments#C.2FC.2B.2B) of different C and C++ [Integrated Development Environments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment). Some of them are free and comes with an up-to-date compilers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My *guess* is that the console window which contains the output flashes by so quickly that you don't have time to see it. You need to put in something to halt the program so you can see the output. One way of doing it is to ask the user to press the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

Something like

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("Hello World\n");
    printf("Press the Enter key to continue\n");
    (void) getc(stdin);
    return 0;
}
```